# Collector resistor value affects the delay in this simple turn-off delay circuit. Why?

Tags: bjt, delay

Here's my simulated circuit:
[image]

As you can see, when plotting the output voltage, the smaller the collector resistor value is, the shorter is the delay.
But why? What BJT graph predicts this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what other effect does changing the value of the collector resistor have on the circuit? What is the transistor actually doing?

Comment: @Finbarr This is a simulation. You are looking at the complete simulated circuit.

Comment: I'm asking you to explain the circuit and how you think it works.

Comment: @Finbarr the transistor is conducting as long as the switch is closed. The moment the switch is opened, it's supposed to keep conducting for a while (delay) as the capacitor discharges. At first I thought this time delay was only dependent on the R2-C1 network but that's not the case here.

Comment: I repeat, then, what other effect does changing the value of the collector resistor have on the circuit?

Comment: In case  @Finbarr is too subtle, what other quantities have you tried plotting?

Comment: I also tried plotting the capacitor's voltage, the current through the base resistor and the base-emitter voltage. 
They certainly don't change with the collector resistance. 

The only thing that changes is the collector voltage and the current through the collector resistor.

Comment: Well... that last one is the key. How does it relate to the current through the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower the load resistance the larger base current is needed to keep the transistor in saturation.
For example for **RL = 1K** and **Vcc = 9V** we have **Ic_max = 9V/1kΩ = 9mA**
Thus, to keep BJT in saturation we need **Ib_min > Ic_max /Hfe ≈ 9mA/100 ≈ 90µA**.
So the minimum capacitor voltage needed to sustain saturation in this case is equal to:

**Vc_min = Vbe_sat + Ib_min*Rb = 0.8V + 90µA x 20kΩ = 2.6V.**

Therefore, the discharge time will be equal to around:

\$T_D = RC \times ln \left(\frac{V_{init} - V_{BE}}{V_{Cmin} - V_{BE}} \right) = 20k\Omega\; 100\mu F \times ln\left(\frac{8.4V}{2V} \right) = 2s \times 1.51 \approx 2.9s \$

These are ballpark calculations (a very rough approximation).

Comment: Those calculations are pretty accurate to what I'm reading from the LTspice plotted values. Thank you very much for your answer with the solved example.

Comment: Those calculations are Hfe dependent. And every BJT will have a slightly different Hfe value. The same is true for Vbe.